# Is there any way to speed up Google Actions SDK development?

Tags: gcloud

I'm new to working with the Google Actions SDK, but my current workflow looks like this:

1. Make changes to app.js.
2. Run 'gcloud app deploy', and wait about 8-10 minutes for the operation to complete.
3. Run 'gactions preview -action_package=action.json -invocation_name="my action"'.
4. Run 'gactions simulate' OR run the web simulator.

Rinse and repeat. Obviously, the most painful step here is the gcloud app deployment. Is there any way to test my changes without having to sit through an 8-10 minute deployment process for each change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host your server (node app.js) where ever you like provided it's accessible via HTTPS, and update your action.json to point to it:

```
"httpExecution": {
  "url": "https://example.com/myapp"
}
```

Then you no longer need to rely on gcloud. Alternatively you could host locally and make use of ngrok. There's a good tutorial here:

https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/ngrok